# Scroller is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, scroller

i am running a javascript to scroll down the image when it is zoomed in but the scroller doesn't work 
here is script

```
    $(function(){
     // Add a custom filter to recognize images from lorempixel (that don't end with ".jpg" or something similar)
            $.tosrus.defaults.media.image = {
                filterAnchors: function( $anchor ) {
                return $anchor.attr( 'href' ).indexOf( 'cdn.shopify.com' ) > -1;
                }
            };

            $('#example-2 a').tosrus({
                pagination  : {
                    add         : true
                },
                caption     : {
                    add         : true
                },
                slides      : {
                    scale       : 'fill'
                }
            });
        });
```

[image: zoomed image that is not scrolling]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('#event-list').scroll(function() {
var curScroll = $(this)[0].scrollTop,
    maxScroll = $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height();

console.log(curScroll, ' :: ', maxScroll);

if ((curScroll >= maxScroll - 200) && !loading) {
    loading = true;

    $(this)[0].scrollTop = curScroll;

    $('.loading').fadeIn('fast');

    if (page <= $('.page').length) {
        loadMore();
    }
}
```

});